# How to wait till animation finish in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

Im trying to make an infinite loop for a carousel when i click a desired div it will be centered at a desired position, if i click the item that is adjacent to the centered position, everything works fine, but if he is more than 1 position away from the center it triggers an effect that doesnt follow the usual logic.

I have tried to solve the problem by checking the distance from the center and than moving the items 1 by 1 n times, but i guess because the loop doesn't wait for the animations to finish im getting this weird effect.

The final outcome should be making an infinite feel to the carousel when you click an item that is 5 positions away from the center it would center it and the ones that are out of view will slide from the respective direction to create a loop

any help will be appreciated, Im relatively new to web dev so a well explained answer will be highly appreciated

JS:

```
const serviceList = document.querySelectorAll('.service__block');

serviceList.forEach(service => {
  service.addEventListener('click', () => {
    markSelectedService(service);
    moveService(checkDistance(service));
  });
});

//Adds the class to the clicked service
function markSelectedService(service) {
  removeSelectedClass();
  service.classList.add('selected');
}

//Removes the selected class from all the services
function removeSelectedClass() {
  serviceList.forEach(service => {
    service.classList.remove('selected');
  });
}

//Check distance from center
function checkDistance(service) {
  let distance = service.dataset.order - 4;
  return distance;
}

//Move the service 1 by 1 n times
function moveService(distance) {
  if (distance > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
      serviceList.forEach(service => {
        service.dataset.order = parseInt(service.dataset.order) - 1;
        if (parseInt(service.dataset.order) === -1) {
          service.dataset.order = 11;
        }
      });
    }
  } else if (distance < 0) {
    distance = distance * -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
      serviceList.forEach(service => {
        service.dataset.order = parseInt(service.dataset.order) + 1;
        if (parseInt(service.dataset.order) === 12) {
          service.dataset.order = 0;
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Link to codepen:
https://codepen.io/tomyshoam/pen/yLLLYyQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to wait for the animation's end to trigger the next one you insert a setInterval and set the interval time to your animation's time.
Example:

```
var i = 0;
var animationInterval = setInterval(function () {

   //YOUR LOGIC HERE

   if (++i === distance) {
     window.clearInterval(animationInterval);
   }
}, 500);
```

**Update**

After some tries I think I got it working how you wanted, although it's not the better way to do it.
I copied the icons list, one to the right side and one to the left, this way the icons will only move to the other side when they are far far away from the user's view and will not trigger that weir behavior.

Code below:
https://codepen.io/diogoperes/pen/oNNNBGY

Comment: The problem now that it actualy goes through each of the steps 1 by 1, what i need is for the animation to .5s to get to the center regardless of how far it is, but the problem is that if you can on an item of position 9 it travels to position 4 as needed, but items 1,2,3 travel straight to their new positions 9, 10, 11 instead of following the patch they need to get there by going 1 by 1 ( -1 )

the solution you provided fixes the problem, but the effect it creates is different from what i need.
thanks alot for taking the time to help me!